# Plot matrix rows with distinct colors

Tags: r, matrix, colors, plot, row

I have a matrix

```
B = matrix(c(1,2,4,1,4,2,1,3.5,4.2,2,2.2,6.5,3,1.2,7.7,1,2.1,1.6,3,5.2,8.2),
           nrow = 7)
```

with 3 columns: the color column (colors from 1-5, representing blue,red,green,yellow,black), the x column and the y column.

I want to plot every points (x,y) with the color from the color column.

First question: what software is best to do so?

Second question: how can I do it with R?

Comment: You can definitely do that in R. But the best is if you provide with a reproducible example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple question finds simple answer:

```
plot(B[,2], B[,3], col=c("blue","red","green","yellow","black")[B[,1]])
```